# Gradle: Unable to initialize POM pom-default.xml: Failed to validate POM

Tags: java, build.gradle, sonatype, gradle-plugin

I am getting 'Unable to initialize POM pom-default.xml: Failed to validate POM' when uploading archive using 'uploadArchives'. I tried maven-publish plugin also but still no luck. Any help will be appriciated.

Below is my gradle.build file:

```
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.2.6.RELEASE'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}") 
    classpath('io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.2.RELEASE')
}
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot' 
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'signing'

jar {
baseName = 'zmailapp'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-ws')
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') 
}


eclipse {
classpath {
     containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
     containers     'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.lau    ncher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8'
}
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
gradleVersion = '2.7'
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar) {
classifier = 'javadoc'
from javadoc
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
classifier = 'sources'
from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

artifacts {
archives javadocJar, sourcesJar
}

signing {
sign configurations.archives
}

group = "com.adadyn"
archivesBaseName = "zmailapp"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

uploadArchives {
repositories {
mavenDeployer {
  beforeDeployment { MavenDeployment deployment ->     signing.signPom(deployment) }

  repository(url: "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy  /maven2/") {
    authentication(userName: ossrhUsername, password: ossrhPassword)
  }

  snapshotRepository(url: "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/") {
    authentication(userName: ossrhUsername, password: ossrhPassword)
  }

  pom.project {
    name 'ZmailApp'
    packaging 'jar'
    // optionally artifactId can be defined here 
    description 'A application used as an example on how to set up pushing  its components to the Central Repository.'
    url 'http://zmailapp.com'

    scm {
      connection 'scm:git:https://github.com/zishan2050/ZmailApp'
      developerConnection 'scm:git:https://github.com/zishan2050/ZmailApp'
      url 'https://github.com/zishan2050/ZmailApp'
    }

    licenses {
      license {
        name 'The Apache License, Version 2.0'
        url 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
      }
    }

    developers {
      developer {
        id 'manfred'
        name 'Manfred Moser'
        email 'manfred@sonatype.com'
      }
    }
  }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the above error by adding below code in pom.project{ } block of gradle.build file.

```
parent { 
  groupId "org.springframework.boot"
  artifactId "spring-boot-starter-parent"
  version "${project.bootVersion}"
}
```